# IPEDS 2020 / 2021 Access database - where to find information about institution name and programs / majors offerred

Tags: databases

Hi I have downloaded the IPEDS 2020 / 2021 Access database - where can I find information about institution name and programs / majors offerred?

Comment: Read [Use the Data](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data), please.